# How are out-of-order and wait-free writes handled?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

As stated in [Guarantees](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperOver.html#Guarantees):

> Sequential Consistency - Updates from a client will be applied in the order that they were sent.

Let's assume a client makes 2 updates (update1 and update2) in a very short time window (I understand zookeeper is good at read-domination applications). So my questions are:

1. Is that possible update2 is received before update1, therefore for zookeeper update1 has later stamp than that of update2? I assume yes due to network connection nature. If this the case that means client will lose its update2 and will have update1. Is there anyway zookeeper can ACK back the client with different stamp or whatever other data that let the client to determine if update2 is really received after update1. Basically zookeeper tells what it sees from server side to client, which gives client some info to act if that's not what the client wants.
2. What if there is a leader failure after receiving and confirming update1 and before receiving update2? I assume such writes are persisted somewhere in disk/DB etc. When the new leader comes back will it catch up first, meaning conduct update1, before confirming update2 back to client?
3. Just curious, since zookeeper claims it supports wait-free writing, does that mean there is a message queue built inside zookeeper to hold incoming writes? Otherwise if the leader has to make sure the update is populated to all other followers, the client is actually being blocked by during this replication process. I am guessing that's part of reason zookeeper does not support heavy write application.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two questions, I think you can find details in [Zookeeper's paper](http://static.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs227/archives/2012/papers/replication/hunt.pdf).

1. It's quite normal that different operations from the same client arrive in disorder to Zookeeper node. But Zookeeper use TCP to ensure that sequential network package will be receive orderly.
2. Leader must write operations in Write-Ahead-Log before it can confirm operations. The problems will diverge in two dimensions. The first situation we should consider is whether the leader could recover before  followers realize leader failure. If yes, nothing bad will happen, all operations in failure time will lost, and client will resend the operations. If not, then we should consider whether the Leader has proposed a proposal before it fails. If it fails before proposing a proposal, then client will know the failure. If it has proposed a proposal, there must be at least one node in the cluster which has got the newest transactions. Then it will be the new Leader in next rolling. When the original Leader recovers from failure, it will realize he's no longer the leader(All transactions of Zookeeper contains a 64-bits transaction id, of which the higher 32 bits represent epoch, and the lower 32 bits represents proposal id). It will communicate with new Leader and then get updated(Sometimes it need truncate it's local transaction log first).
3. I don't know the details since I haven't read ZooKeeper's source code. But Leader only needs over half acknowledge from followers before it response to clients. Zookeeper provide both blocking and non-blocking API and you can choose what you like.